# (Partial/total/well-) order vs ordering

Tags: terminology, order-theory

Order or ordering – what is the difference? Is either correct? Is one British and one American English?

Not exactly a maths question but probably still the best place to ask.

Comment: I am neither a native English speaker nor an expert, but my first thought upon reading this is that "a partial order" is a pair $(X,\leq)$ of a set together with a relation, whereas "a partial ordering" only refers to the relation $\leq$.

Comment: @Mees: *Partial order* can refer either to the pair or to the relation — one can say, for instance, that $\subseteq$ is a partial order on $\wp(X)$ — but your distinction is pretty common in my experience, and I’ve rarely (if ever) seen *partial ordering* applied to the pair rather than to the relation.

Comment: Wait, are you asking about partial vs total vs well or order vs ordering?

Comment: @NobleMushtak: I'm asking about order vs ordering.